# Is it possible to modify the behavior of Listable?

Tags: function-construction, attributes

Is it possible to achieve `Thread`-like behavior using the `Listable` attribute either on a symbol or in a pure function (or probably in `Compile`)?

What I would be interested in obtaining is, to have something like:

```
SetAttributes[func, Listable]
```

or a relevant definition involving `Listable`, that would transform something like:

```
l = {
 {{a}, {c, d, e}, {f, g}}, 
 {{h, i}, {j}, {m, n}}, 
 {{o, p}, {q, r, s}, {t}}
};
```

into

```
{
 {func[a], func[c, d, e], func[f, g]}, 
 {func[h, i], func[j], func[m, n]}, 
 {func[o, p], func[q, r, s], func[t]}
}
```

Again, what I'm trying to do is transform a possibly non-rectangular array using `func` *only* by making use of the attribute `Listable`, in any of its possible incarnations.

Comment: And `Apply[func, l, {2}]` does not do what you want?

Comment: yes it does but I am interested in using `Listable` to achieve the same effect if it is possible

Comment: Your question, if I understand it correctly, can be rephrased as: Is there a kernel hook that allows me to change the behavior of the attribute `Listable`?  I know of none and I think it likely that none exists. I certainly hope there is none because such a hook would be extremely dangerous.

Comment: @m_goldberg I was hoping there was a situation where it were possible to allow `func` (or another auxiliary function of functions related to `func`) to achieve behavior analogous to using `Hold` or similar constructs. Thank you for your insight.